# Show scrollbars when the control's content overlaps its visible boundaries

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, scroll

I am working with List Box control in Vb.net , The problem is, I am populating List Box from a Slider control's values, At times, values reach out of its visible rectangle area.
I want to see the updated values during slider move,I have added both the events

```
_SelectedIndexChanged
_SelectedValueChanged
```

but they both not triggering when I add values to List Box using Slider Control.

My tentative code for showing the latest value is this, but I am not getting where to type.

```
{
    Dim count As Integer
    count = lb.Items.Count     ' lb is the ListBox's variable
    lb.SetSelected(count - 1, True) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to just scroll to the bottom or select the last one:

```
lb.SelectedIndex =lb.SelectedIndex + 1
```

or to scroll it:

```
lb.TopIndex = lb.Items.Count - 1
```

add it after your code to add items.  The latter is generally better because it doesnt change what the user might have selected already.

Comment: Wonderful, Its Working.   lb.TopIndex = lb.Items.Count - 1